# How, when, where to set script variables of libtool? (e.g. hardcode_minus_L)

Tags: autoconf, libtool

Long story short: I worked on [relative rpath linking](https://github.com/chros73/rtorrent-ps/blob/78f1b33abb63e3986910674a384b6832e1220ccf/build.sh#L145) with [this script](https://github.com/chros73/rtorrent-ps/blob/78f1b33abb63e3986910674a384b6832e1220ccf/build.sh) (that [uses](https://github.com/chros73/rtorrent-ps/blob/78f1b33abb63e3986910674a384b6832e1220ccf/build.sh#L333) automake, autoconf, libtool).
The problem is that the final `rpath`/`runpath` entry in the binary executable or `so` file still has the absolute path:

- it turned out libtool is configured by default like this with [hardcode_libdir_flag_spec](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/libtool-script-contents.html#libtool-script-contents) to include any `-L` value if it's set in `LDFLAGS`

The only question remains: how and at which point (what's the proper way) can I set other libtool variables, like `hardcode_minus_L`. (I've searched for it on the net, but I couldn't find anything.)

I tried to do the following:

- after [configure](https://github.com/chros73/rtorrent-ps/blob/78f1b33abb63e3986910674a384b6832e1220ccf/build.sh#L387) is called I tried to replace the value of the variable with `sed` in `libtool` file (in the proper directory): it worked but when `make` is called it overwrote the whole `libtool` file again (it was regenerated)

Note, that 2 binary files are effected by this, entry for `rpath`/`runpath` with `objdump -p`:

- [libcurl.so](https://github.com/chros73/rtorrent-ps/blob/78f1b33abb63e3986910674a384b6832e1220ccf/build.sh#L349) : `RUNPATH  /home/user1/lib/rtorrent-0.9.7-1.5.3/lib:$ORIGIN/../lib`
- [rtorrent](https://github.com/chros73/rtorrent-ps/blob/78f1b33abb63e3986910674a384b6832e1220ccf/build.sh#L387) : `RUNPATH  $ORIGIN/../lib:/home/user1/lib/rtorrent-0.9.7-1.5.3/lib`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it's fairly easy to modify these variables in `configure.ac`, no need for `sed` - after fiddling around and taking a look into the generated scripts. The only thing can be confusing that these variables can be applied to 
 `tags` defined in the given project.

E.g. to change `hardcode_libdir_flag_spec` to an empty value in `rtorrent` project (means it will break compilation), you would insert into `configure.ac`:

```
_LT_TAGVAR(hardcode_libdir_flag_spec, )=""
_LT_TAGVAR(hardcode_libdir_flag_spec, CXX)=""
_LT_TAGVAR(hardcode_minus_L, )=yes
_LT_TAGVAR(hardcode_minus_L, CXX)=yes
```

The 2nd parameter is the `tag` or `default` tag if it's empty.

Comment: Note that I couldn't solve the original issue with this no matter what I tried with them :) So I just stuck with `chrpath` util to change the generated `rpath` entries in the binaries.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if modifying the generated `libtool` script is the best approach to solve your problem. But if you go this way, you need to make the approach robust by executing your `sed` command within `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS`.

The `libtool` script is generated during config.status as an configuration command (`AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS`: https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Configuration-Commands) .

```
config.status: executing libtool commands
```

You can modify this generated file by adding another `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS`.
We use following to alter the `prefer_static_libs` variable:

```
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS([libtool-fix-linker-preference],                                                                                                                      
    [${SED} -e '1,/prefer_static_libs=/ s/prefer_static_libs=.*$/prefer_static_libs=yes/' \
     libtool > libtool.fix && mv libtool.fix libtool])
```

You need to trigger your `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS` after `LT_INIT`. 
configure/config.status reports the execution:

```
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing libtool-fix-linker-preference commands
```

Hope that helps,

Christian

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work with rtorrent: it fires up [autogen.sh](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/blob/226e670decf92e7adaa845a6982aca4f164ea740/autogen.sh) at first and it doesn't trigger the self defined AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS at the beginning of [configure.ac](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/blob/226e670decf92e7adaa845a6982aca4f164ea740/configure.ac): only the following line is visible at the end of configure output: `config.status: executing libtool commands`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, again, it told me that I'm going in the right direction  (so I upvoted yours).